# Retrive all data to select option list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to Retrieve all data from API Through using Vue Form and Axios. but  it cannot be retrieved right now. Maybe i missed something. In this case i want to retrieve Brand of car, when one brand is selected in other select option it will change the series list base on chosen brand. Need your help.

here's the code for vue.js

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Merek</label>
  <select class="select-dropdown-no-search form-control" v-model="merk" @change="listSeri()" name="merek" id="merek">
<option value="">--Pilih--</option>
<option v-for='data in merks' :value='data.MerkId'>{{ data.MerkName }}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Seri</label>
    <select class="select-dropdown-no-search form-control" v-model="seri" @change="listSilinder()" name="seri" id="seri">
<option value="">--Pilih--</option>
<option v-for='data in series' :value='data.MerkId'>{{ data.MerkName }}</option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the code for the vue.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import API from '../API';

var urlAddStock = API.url.host + '/addstock';
var urlMerkList = API.url.host + '/merk';
var urlSeriList = API.url.host + '/seri';
var urlSilinderList = API.url.host + '/silinder';
var urlTipeList = API.url.host + '/tipe';

//Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
var inputMobile = {
  init: function() {
    this.vueConfig();
    API.auth();
  },
  vueConfig: function() {
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        stockSubmit: false,

        merk: "",
        merks: [],

        seri: "",
        series: [],
        access_token: ""
      },
      methods: {
        submitStock: function() {
          let self = this;
          this.stockSubmit = true;
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: urlAddStock,
            data: {
              MerkId: this.merk,
              merk: "",
              SeriId: this.seri,
              seri: "",

              access_token: localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);

            if (res.data.message === "Berhasil Menambahkan Data") {
              self.stockSubmit = false;
            } else {
              self.stockSubmit = false;
            }

          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            self.stockSubmit = false;
          });
        },
        listMerk: function() {
          let self = this;
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: urlMerkList,
            data: {
              itemid: 6,
              access_token: localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
          }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.data.message === "Berhasil Mengambil Data Merk") {
              this.merks = response.data;

            }

          }, err => {
            console.log(err);

          });

        },
        listSeri: function() {
          let self = this;
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: urlSeriList,
            data: {
              merkid: this.merk,
              access_token: localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            if (res.data.message === "Berhasil Mengambil Data Seri") {
              this.series = response.data;
            }

          }, err => {
            console.log(err);

          });

        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new Array reference in `this.series`. Try changing this:

```js
if(res.data.message === "Berhasil Mengambil Data Seri"){
  // assign new array reference using 'spread operator'
  this.series = [...response.data];
}
```